# Create test of text direction (luatex)

Tags: macros, luatex, expansion, right-to-left

With luatex there is `\textdir` to change text direction and `tex.textdir` which  give string representing text direction.

I have created this macro to test text direction which supposedly gives `TLT` inside left to right context and `TRT` inside right to left context, but my macro does not give the desired result

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\edef\dir{TLT}
\def\testdir{\directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}}
\def\foo{\ifx\dir\testdir TLT \else TRT \fi}

\begin{document}

%\textdir TRT

\foo ; \directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifx` does no expansion and only looks at the first level expansion when comparing two macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ifx` only *looks* at the first level expansion when comparing two control sequences and cannot compare strings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ifdirTLT}{mm}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { TLT } { \lua_now:n { tex.print(tex.textdir) } }
   { #1 }
   { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textdir TLT

\ifdirTLT{TLT}{TRT}; \directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}

\textdir TRT

\ifdirTLT{TLT}{TRT}; \directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand the \directlua before the test. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\tl_if_eq:nnTF {xn}
\def\foo{\tl_if_eq:xnTF{\directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}}{TLT}{TLT}{TRT}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%

\foo ; \directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}

\textdir TRT
\foo ; \directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an equivalent macro  without latex3?

Comment: You can at first expand the command with `\edef\tmpa{\directlua ...}` and then use `\ifx\tmpa\dir` but expl3 solutions are imho better (and egreg's test is better than mine, comparing this as string is cleaner.)

Comment: The  expansion should come  just before the test like this
`\def\foo{\edef\testdir{\directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir)}}
\ifx\testdir\dir TLT \else TRT \fi}`

For the LaTeX3  syntax I find it a bit difficult.

Comment: @SalimBou Just do the comparison in Lua. `\directlua{tex.print(tex.textdir == "TLT" and "TLT" or "TRT")}`

Comment: @HenriMenke I would like to create `\if`  conditional which test the text direction to change some  tex dimensions not just to print `TLT` or `TRT` like this
`\if<text direction is TLT>  do this \else do that \fi`

Comment: The latex3 syntax may look at first a bit unfamiliar, but obviously you didn't know how to use correctly the more friendly looking \ifx, so why do you want to stick to it?