Is there a possibility to exchange roles of r and l columns in RTL tabular (lualatex engine)
I have this example of a tabular in right to left context, text in r column is  aligned to the left and text in l column is aligned to the right. my aim is to exchange roles of r and l columns in the natural form as it is happening in left to right context, so with l column text should be left aligned and with r column text should be  right aligned.
\documentclass{article}

\textdir TRT

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\AddToHook{env/tblr/begin}{%
\ifnum\textdirection=0\else \mathdir TRT\fi
}

\SetTblrInner[tblr,talltblr]{
  cells={preto={\mathdir TLT}}, measure=vbox
}
    

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|l|r|}
\hline
First column & Second column\\
Alpha & Alpha \\
Beta  & Beta \\
Gamma & Gamma \\
Delta & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482749/107497 seems relevant, but I couldn't get it to work.

I don't think this is related only to tables, in LuaTeX the right_skip glue nodes are not actually added to the right, it is added to the end of the line, and so \raggedright actually means "ragged at the end of the line". The naming is quite unfortunate, and in fact I wish the naming in the user space was changed.

@UdiFogiel Interesting discussion thanks for the link.
